# After=multi-user.target and others not working in a systemd service

Tags: systemd, services

I have a service that works that only works if it runs after the `dhcpcd.service` because it performs a github pull, and it can't resolve the host unless DHCP is up. `network.target` is finished long before the DHCP service completes. Please note that the user `michael` won't be logged in (its a server) when the service should run.

The problem is I can't get it to run late enough to work, without resorting to some super long ugly delay to cover all situations, e.g.

```
ExecStartPre=sleep 30
```

Here is the service `updatecontinue.service` (one of many `After=` combinations I have tried):

```
# man systemd.service
# man systemd.unit
#
# Debug with (will print errors at the bottom, time is in UTC!):
#   -n50 to show 50 lines
#   sudo systemctl status updatecontinue
#
# Or to get a plot (open with chrome so its searchable):
#   systemd-analyze plot > ~/plot.svg

[Unit]
Description=Check if an update is halfway through, if yes, then update/enable OverlayFS/reboot

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/michael/.venv/terminal/bin/python3 /home/michael/terminal/script/update.py --check
After=dhcpcd.service
User=michael

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here you can see it is not starting where it is defined:

### NOTE

Even if I set after to:

```
After=dhcpcd.service systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service systemd-timesyncd.service
```

[image]

### Note for RON's suggestion

`systemctl get-default` reports `graphical.target`

Using this service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check if an update is halfway through, if yes, then update/enable OverlayFS/reboot

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/michael/.venv/terminal/bin/python3 /home/michael/terminal/script/update.py --check
After=default.target
TimeoutStartSec=0
User=michael

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Defining `WantedBy=multi-user.target` and `After=multi-user.target` adds a bit of a conflict that systemd tries to resolve.  You can see a larger explanation/experiment lower in this answer.

Instead, try to figure out why your service fails if it runs too early.  Instead of running `After=multi-user.target`, run `After=` that service/target.

My guess is to add `After=network.target` if your only issue is with networking.

If you need a user to be logged in, use the `--user` bus.

If you need a graphical session, then consider `WantedBy=graphical.target` on the system bus, or `WantedBy=graphical-session.target` on the user bus.

---

When you use `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, it will give `multi-user.target` a `Wants=updatecontinue.service` relationship.

This simply means: `updatecontinue.service` will be started if `multi-user.target` is started.  If `updatecontinue.service` fails to start, it does not affect `multi-user.target`.

Then, you give `updatecontinue.service` a `Requires=multi-user.target` relationship.  That's a significant conflict.  `Requires=` is almost the same as `Wants=` (If you start *this*, *that* will also be started). Except:  if *that* unit fails to activate, *this* unit will not start.

So you really just have two units that start each other which probably isn't what you intended.  I would drop the `Requires=` dependency for the sake of clarity.

---

The `Before`/`After` relationships do work, here is an example of two services interacting without `Before`/`After`:

```
$ systemctl --user cat {early,late}.service
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/early.service
[Unit]
Wants=late.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=sleep 2
ExecStart=sleep 20

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/late.service
[Service]
ExecStart=sleep 5

$ systemctl --user start early
$ journalctl --user --since "2 minutes ago" --no-hostname
Mar 08 15:54:42 systemd[1064]: Starting early.service...
Mar 08 15:54:42 systemd[1064]: Started late.service.
Mar 08 15:54:44 systemd[1064]: Started early.service.
```

You can see the services start simultaneously.

Now let's try giving `late.service` a `After=early.service` relationship:

```
$ systemctl --user cat {early,late}.service
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/early.service
[Unit]
Wants=late.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=sleep 2
ExecStart=sleep 20

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/late.service
[Unit]
After=early.service
[Service]
ExecStart=sleep 5

$ systemctl --user start early
$ journalctl --user --since "2 minutes ago" --no-hostname
Mar 08 16:01:09 systemd[1064]: Starting early.service...
Mar 08 16:01:11 systemd[1064]: Started early.service.
Mar 08 16:01:11 systemd[1064]: Started late.service.
```

In this case, you can see `late.service` was started after `early.service` finish its `ExecStartPre` (waits for the unit to become `active (running)`).

---

Unlike services, targets do not go into "Starting" states.  Instead, they are "reached".  Let's try the same thing with `early.target` and `late.service`, but `late.service` takes time to start:

```
$ systemctl --user cat early.target late.service
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/early.target
[Unit]
Wants=late.service

# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/late.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=sleep 2
ExecStart=sleep 5

$ systemctl --user start early.target
$ journalctl --user --since "2 minutes ago" --no-hostname
Mar 08 16:07:27 systemd[1064]: Starting late.service...
Mar 08 16:07:29 systemd[1064]: Started late.service.
Mar 08 16:07:29 systemd[1064]: Reached target early.target.
```

We see that it takes 2 seconds for `early.target` to get "reached".  This means targets are only "reached" when their "Wants=" all complete their "activating" phases and enter the "active (running)" state.

Learning this, we can now understand why a `After=foo.target` mixed with a `WantedBy=foo.target` is a bit of a conflict.  `foo.target` is waiting for us to start before it is reached. Meanwhile, we want `foo.target` to be reached before we start.

Comment: Thank you for in depth answer!! I'm still doing through it. Sorry, some copy/paste issues with the username mix up between dev/and prod, I corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for the undersetanding. An answer I read on SO said Before=/After= sets the order, and Wantedby= set dependencies, and is orthognal to order, but you have demonstrated that is not the case. Using your suggestions I have determined the key dependancy is the DHCP service. I have removed the conflict but still can't get it to start late enough. If you have time would you please see my update question. By the way is the `--user` bus the same thing as `D-Bus`? Trying to google it/read the man pages keeps show `D-bus results`.

Comment: The `--user` bus is not the same as `D-Bus`.  The `--user` bus runs everything as your user under `user@.service`.   It is activated as you log in.  It has its own targets. Service files in the `--user` bus go in `~/.config/systemd/user`.  You are working on the `--system` bus (default).  See `man systemd.special` for targets related to the `--user` bus.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know about `man systemd.special`! I really appreciate your help! Big thank you! Ps I was placing `After=` in the `[Service]` section instead of the `[Unit]` section, and thats why it was not working, gosh how silly of me!

Comment: Oh, wow.  I should have noticed it was in the service section.  Whoops!

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to make the service run as late as possible

Do `After=default.target`

*default.target* will equal whatever `systemctl set-default` is set to.

complete list of SysV runlevels and their corresponding systemd targets is

```
0    runlevel0.target, poweroff.target     {Shut down and power off the system.}
1    runlevel1.target, rescue.target       {Set up a rescue shell.}
2    runlevel2.target, multi-user.target   {Set up a non-graphical multi-user system.}
3    runlevel3.target, multi-user.target   {Set up a non-graphical multi-user system.}
4    runlevel4.target, multi-user.target   {Set up a non-graphical multi-user system.}
5    runlevel5.target, graphical.target    {Set up a graphical multi-user system.}
6    runlevel6.target, reboot.target       {Shut down and reboot the system.}
```

It's basically either `systemctl set-default graphical.target` or `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` is all that's ever done.  You can `systemctl get-default` to see what it is currently set to.

> I have a service that works if I start it manually, but it does not start at boot.

It's kinda easy to mess up the syntax in the service file or what the `ExecStart` equals, such that if you manually run the script ExecStart defines it will work but under the conditions of systemd service it'll fail to run.  Really got to test and debug,  I don't think it's a "timing" issue. Do something simple like `/usr/bin/echo hello > /testfile` and first make sure that will run manually, if it does but then does not run automated from the systemd service then it's a mistake you made somewhere along the way; something like this wouldn't be a timing issue.  Then take steps tweaking `Before` or `Requires` one at a time until it stops working.

My `administration.service` file located in `/etc/systemd/system/` is

```
#!/bin/bash

[Unit]
Description=administration
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/root/scripts/administration.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

my `/root/scripts/administration.sh` file is `root.root with` -rwx------`and has`#!/bin/bash` at the top of it; simply mess this first line up and my service won't run.

be sure to check `systemctl list-unit-files | grep administration` needs to show as *enabled*   {adjust syntax accordingly to meet your needs}.

`systemctl daemon-reload` if your `administration.service` file is present but does not show up when doing `systemctl list-unit-files`

I'll let someone else post if /etc/systemd/system/ is the proper location to generate user-defined services; all I know it works for me if the service is root owned and makes sense if its admin in nature.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ron, I tried your suggestions, and it does not noticeable delay the service. Please see my updated question with a section 'Note for Ron'. Adding a delay proced that the service does indeed work if started after the DHCP service.

Comment: It is my understanding that /etc/systemd/system/ is the right place for local/user-defined services.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to code on little sleep is not a good idea, the issue was, as silly as `After=` must be in the `[Unit]` section, not the `[Service]` section!