# Why service does not retrigger as part of other service

Tags: systemd, services, dependencies

I have services A and B. B should triggers only after retrigger of the service A. Service A triggers every 10 minutes by timer. Service A works correctly all the time(every 10 minutes), but service B has not ever executed after service A. What i did wrong?

Service A:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service A
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=XXX

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Timer for service A:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for service A

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=10min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service B:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service B
After=serviceA.service
BindsTo=serviceA.service
PartOf=serviceA.service

[Service]
ExecStart=XX

[Install]
WantedBy=serviceA.service
```

Comment: Anything in the system log after running `systemctl daemon-reload`? I guess `BindsTo` and `PartOf` are not to be used together; that might be considered an error. Have you tried using only `BindsTo`?

Comment: I think in `Service A` you'll have to add this line: `Wants=serviceB.service` under `[Unit]` section

Comment: HaukeLaging yes i tried with only BindsTo, but this is also not working, i dont see any errors in journalctl
EdgarMagallon thanks this is working. Can you explain why this was not working "WantedBy=serviceA.service" ?

Comment: @Buczo Oh, I haven't noticed the directive `WantedBy=serviceA.service` in your systemd unit. Using `Wants` directive will work without using `WantedBy`. However in your case, if you want to use `WantedBy` you should enable the service **serviceB** (and the **ServiceA** as well to run at startup). So try using `sudo systemctl enable serviceB.service` and when the **ServiceA** runs this will launch the **ServiceB**

Comment: @Buczo about your **ServiceA** check [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693533/414186). You should not use `After=multi-user.target` and `WantedBy=multi-user.target` together.